# Creating function for hybris template engine

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to link a product with editorial content from another platform (wordpress by example).
Is it possible to create function in the template engine (like in smarty) which will detect a specific tag ?

For example, if in my product description there is this king of tag `{% post_related=ID %}`
then my function in the template engine would replace that tag by html code or call a webservice....

Also, what template engine is use in Hybris ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I not sure on template engine but hybris comes with there very own cms which is the base of all the website related content.It is based on spring+jstl.Or in parts of hybris like email and cockpit velocity templates are also used
You can check out [hybris tutorial](http://www.hybrishub.com)